# What do the different color auras do?

Tags: dungeon-siege-3

Several bosses have different color circles around them. On one loading screen it said that the orange causes fire damage to you, and I've fought a few things with a blue-ish one that drained my focus, but I've seen others that I can't figure out. What do they all do?

Comment: As bwarner's comment is not on your question - just noting that there's a suggestion for screenshots to clarify what you mean by auras.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are five auras:

- **Green:** Healing Aura
- **Orange:** Flame Aura (fire-based periodic damage)
- **Purple:** Drain Focus aura
- **Red:** Speed aura
- **White:** Toughness aura (increases enemy's armor)

Note these colors roughly apply to your characters' abilities too. For example, the badges for Anjali's fire talents and abilities are orange-tinted, and many of the healing abilities are green-tinted. I guess you can consider it to be Dungeon Siege III's version of an elemental system.